# How to random {1|2|3|4} by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

```
<div class="xxx">Number is {1|2|3|4}, and {one|two|three|four}</div>

<div class="yyy"></div>
```

...

```
var data = $(".xxx").text();

$(".yyy").html(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tQeCv/

I just need this input :

**Number is {1|2|3|4}, and {one|two|three|four}**

and random like this
Output:

**Number is 3, and four**

I dont know how to do ... sorry :(

Comment: what is your question/objective? I don't know, sorry :(

Comment: i dont know this is object or array .... this is JSON ?

Comment: If you're reffering to `data`, it's just a strange string? Try explaining what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: I trying to do...
Input : Number is {1|2|3|4}, and {one|two|three|four}
Output : Numberis 2, and four

(Just random words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not JSON.  I assume you you want to split the 1,2, 3 and 4 elements up randomly. You would have to split the data up on the | character and then order your results randomly (Or write your own shuffle algorithm).

```
var data = $(".xxx").text(); // initial data

var results = data.split("|"); // split on the "|" and store into results
```

You would then have to get a random element from the array:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1); // random number (no more than 4 or the array will be out of bounds)
```

Shuffle/Display the data:

```
var firstElement = results[randomNumber];
randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var secondElement = results[randomNumber];
```

And so on....

Comment: The text parsing step isn't perfect - should only extract & split what's in between `{}`s.

Comment: i dont understand so really , can you make demo on this http://jsfiddle.net/tQeCv/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something simple to begin with, like understanding split() etc.

Here's something:

```
var data = $(".xxx").text(),
    numbs = data.split('{')[1].split('}')[0].split('|'),
    words = data.split('{')[2].split('}')[0].split('|'),
    newdata = data.split('{')[0]+' '+numbs[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbs.length)];
    newdata += data.split('}')[1].split('{')[0]+' '+words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];

$(".yyy").html(newdata);

​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tQeCv/4/)

Then move on to replacing with regular expressions.

**EDIT:**

To make it more dynamic, and work with more placeholders, you could do something like this with a little regex use:

```
var data = $(".xxx").text(),
    placeholder = data.match(/{(.*?)}/gi);

$.each(placeholder, function(i,e) {
    var options = e.split('|'),
        randOpt = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
    data = data.replace(e, randOpt.replace(/({|})/g, ''));
});

$(".yyy").html(data);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tQeCv/10/)
    ​

Comment: one thing... if i have to random all of content ? like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/tQeCv/9/   <--- this is work only 2 groups

Comment: @l2aelba - See my updated answer for an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math` object `.random()` method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```
function randomNumber()  
{  
  num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (1 - 4) + 4); 
  $(".yyy").text(num) 
}
```

Comment: i only want to make this input to output like this :

Number is 3, and four